# Implementing yahoo chat icon

Tags: php, email, yahoo

Code:

```
<a href = 'ymsgr:sendim?your_yahoo_id'>Send me a message</a>
```

How should I know if the email field is yahoo mail address?

Answer (score 1):

See if it matches a yahoo domain:

A simple implementation would look like this - it's not foolproof (matches foo@yahoo.searchengines.com), but I don't think it has to be:

```
if (preg_match('/@yahoo\./i'))
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use RegEx Patterns, to check the link for a yahoo e-mailadress.

Sample (Modified RFC 2822 Standard)

> [a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@yahoo{1,1}?.a-z0-9?